# How to fill SQLite database in android?

Tags: android, sqlite

I wanna develop an application which has a database which is filled with data. How should I fill the database with data? which of the following should I do?
1- Write a little android app and fill the database and somehow get access to the database file and put that in the app. (I think this is bad)
2- Use some kind of sqlite software to fill the database file and then access the database file and put that in the app.(Again I think this is bad)
3-Any other method.

Answer (score 0):

If the data is not huge, you can download the data from server and fill sqlite database when the user first starts the app.

If the data is huge, you can store the data in a file and put under /res/raw folder of the apk and write code to copy those data to sqlite when the app starts for first time.

Comment: thanks, but what if the data is large? (we have many pictures.)

Comment: You should have the actual image files in server. Only store the URL to image in android app.